# C#: How do you use Mutex objects to sync multiple Threading.Timers when the threads come from the ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Perhaps it's because I'm trying to write code when I'm tired, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to ensure two different timers don't try to execute at the same time.

This is in a Windows Store (UWP) app.  I have two System.Threading.Timer timers.  I am using a Mutex to synchronize between them.  Most of the time that seems to work fine, but sometimes the timers seem to end up on the same thread (based on looking at Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId).  Timer1 claims the mutex, and then Timer2 fires and successfully claims the mutex as well because it's on the same thread.  Disaster follows.

Any suggestions on the right way to deal with this requirement?

**UPDATE**
Adding some code per request.  I think I've boiled this down to its essence.

```
    private void StartCheckRefreshTimer() {
        if (_timer1 != null) return;

        _timer1 = new Timer(Timer1Expired, null, 0,
            MagicStrings.FrequencyToCheckForRefresh*1000);
    }


    private async void Timer1Expired(object state) {
        if (!_myMutex.WaitOne(5000)) 
            DebugMutex("Timer1Expired. Timed out waiting for mutex.");
        else {
            try {
                DebugMutex($"Timer1Expired.  Claimed the mutex.  Thread id: {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
                // await Do something that needs to be in a critical section.
            }
            finally {
                DebugMutex($"Timer1Expired.  Releasing the mutex.  Thread id: {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
                _myMutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }

    private Timer _timer2;

    private async void Timer2Expired(object state) {
        if (!_myMutex.WaitOne(5000)) {
            DebugMutex("Timer2Expired. Timed out waiting for mutex.");
        }
        else {
            try {
                DisposeTimer2();
                DebugMutex($"Timer2Expired.  Claimed the mutex. Thread Id: {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
                // await Do something else that needs to be in a critical section.
            }
            finally {
                DebugMutex($"Timer2Expired. Releasing mutex. Thread Id: {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
                _myMutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }

    private void SomethingHappensThatMakesTimer2Start() {
        lock (this) {
            var interval = MagicStrings.DelayAfterPushRequiredBeforePushing*1000;
            if (_timer2 != null) {
                DebugMutex($"Resetting timer to go off at {DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(interval).ToString("T")}");
                _timer2.Change(interval, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            else {
                DebugMutex($"Creating timer to go off at {DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(interval).ToString("T")}");
                _timer2 = new Timer(Timer2Expired, null, interval, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DisposeTimer2() {
        if (_timer2 != null) {
            _timer2.Dispose();
            _timer2 = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: At least, share with us a part of your code to let us see what you've done.

Comment: Also, btw, I'm currently trying the obvious path of just having one timer that checks to see if it's time to run code (either the Timer1 code or the Timer2 code).  Since it's just one timer, I think that would make the whole issue pretty much moot.

Comment: Your mutex code is pretty straight forward and seem fine, but I see an issue with `_timer2` not being thread-safe. `DisposeTImer2()` is not protected under `lock(this)`, so it is possible that `_timer2.Change(..)`  can be execued after `_timer2` has been disposed.

Comment: I like how `MagicStrings` appear to contain magic numbers ...

Comment: Thanks Viet. Good catch.

Comment: Yeah, MagicStrings became a handy place to put anything magical. Might be time to rename that...

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense. If the same thread _were_ executing both timers, it would not be possible for one timer event to be raised while the other was executing, the timer object can't get control back until the first timer event handler has completed. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it would not be possible to state exactly where your problem is.

Comment: Thanks, and noted.  It probably won't happen soon.  It's a large project, and I'm trying to get into beta within the next week.  If I can get this working and stable with a single timer, that's the path I'm going to take.  I have to get past this and onto actual product features.  Stopping to create a working, buildable sample that reproduces the issue isn't on the radar.  I appreciate your taking the time to look and comment, though. 

Also, I agree with your assessment.  I am curious as to what is going on, and hopefully I'll be able to get back to this in the future and analyze it.